# Deleting row from list view using alert box in android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have retrieved some data from sqlite database to custom `ListView`. Now when I view the data in list view I want to click on a row and an alert box should appear to tell me do you want to delete this row? If I click yes then the particular row should be deleted please help me in this situation I am posting my code right down

```
public class UserDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    String[] projections = {};

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "userinfo.db";
    private static final Integer DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String CREAT_QUERY =
            "CREATE TABLE "+ UserContracts.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME+"("+ UserContracts.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME+" TEXT,"+
                    UserContracts.NewUserInfo.USER_MOB+" TEXT,"+ UserContracts.NewUserInfo.USER_EMAIL+" TEXT);";
    public UserDbHelper (Context context){    
     super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS","Database created / opened...");    
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(CREAT_QUERY);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "Table created...");
    }

    public void addInformation(String name,String mob,String email,SQLiteDatabase db) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(UserContracts.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME,name);
        contentValues.put(UserContracts.NewUserInfo.USER_MOB,mob);
        contentValues.put(UserContracts.NewUserInfo.USER_EMAIL,email);
        db.insert(UserContracts.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "One row inserted");
    }

    public Cursor getInformation(SQLiteDatabase db){
      Cursor cursor;
        String[] projections = {UserContracts.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME, UserContracts.NewUserInfo.USER_MOB,
                UserContracts.NewUserInfo.USER_EMAIL};
        cursor=db.query(UserContracts.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME,projections,null,null,null,null,null);
        return cursor;
    }

    public void deleteInformation(String projections, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        String selection = UserContracts.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME+"LIKE?";
        String[] selection_args = {projections};
        sqLiteDatabase.delete(UserContracts.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME,selection,selection_args);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

And below is my another activity in which I wrote an alert box but I am not getting the required result here is the code

```
List list;
ListView listView;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
UserDbHelper userDbHelper;
Cursor cursor;
ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;
Context context;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.data_list_layout);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_layout);
    listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
    userDbHelper = new UserDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = userDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = userDbHelper.getInformation(sqLiteDatabase);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){

        do {

            String name,mobile,email;
            name = cursor.getString(0);
            mobile = cursor.getString(1);
            email = cursor.getString(2);
            DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(name,mobile,email);
            listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);

        }while (cursor.moveToNext());

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, final int position, long arg2) {

                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DataListActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("Do you want to delete this from database?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        listDataAdapter.remove(listDataAdapter.getItem(0));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Removed from list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is my list data adapter class

```
public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    public ListDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);    
    }

    static class LayoutHandler{    
       TextView NAME,MOBILE,EMAIL;    
    }
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    public void add(Object object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }    

    @Override
    public void remove(Object position) {
        super.remove(position);    
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {    
        View row = convertView;
        LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
        if (row == null){

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
            layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
            layoutHandler.NAME = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_user_name);
            layoutHandler.MOBILE = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_user_mobile);
            layoutHandler.EMAIL = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_user_email);
            row.setTag(layoutHandler);
        }
        else {    
            layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler)row.getTag();    
        }

        DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider)this.getItem(position);
        layoutHandler.NAME.setText(dataProvider.getName());
        layoutHandler.MOBILE.setText(dataProvider.getMobile());
        layoutHandler.EMAIL.setText(dataProvider.getEmail());

        return row;    
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated thank you :)

Comment: What is the problem? Is the item not removing from the listview or is the item not being removed from your list? If it's not being removed from your listview, have you tried `listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after you remove the item?

Comment: thank you its deleting but i didn't tried listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); do you have any idea where should i put this code? thank you

Comment: Your code should look like this inside the postive button handler
`listDataAdapter.remove(listDataAdapter.getItem(0));`

`listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

`Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Removed from list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: it does not working i think it just redraw my list view but no changes

Comment: when i close my app and open it again all the data is still there and it is not notified what is wrong in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get id of the row to the alert dialog. One solution would then be to write a delete method in your `ListDataAdapter`:

```
public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

  //Your existing code here

  // Remove your element from list and inform Adapter that data set has changed
  public boolean removeRow(int rowIndex){
    if(list.size() > rowIndex){
        list.remove(rowIndex);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  } 
}
```

At the place you need to remove a row, simply get instance to your adapter and call `removeRow` method. Example for removing 3th row:

```
((ListDataAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).removeRow(2);
```

But beware, `notifyDataSetChanged()` will basically redraw your ListView, so if this is a common action, try to use optimised version - RecyclerView. At first it looks a bit more complicated, but usually it is worth it.

You can find some good tutorials, like this one:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html

Comment: Thank you so much dear you guys are amazing but i did as you told but i can't get it worked that's because i am missing something one thing is how can i get it id? because i don't have it's id and please tell me to where put the code notifyDataSetChanged()? may be it's because i didn't put it right? please correct me and thank you!

Comment: change this line listDataAdapter.remove(listDataAdapter.getItem(0));
to:
listDataAdapter.remove(position);
in your OnItemClickListener

Comment: Thank you so much dear i tried it it's working but when i close the app and open it again the items are still there now i have to update the row i think to get rid of this problem and thank you so much dear

Comment: Well, you should remove it from your database as well at the same time you remove it from ListView. You can get the desired element from your ContentProvider / database

Comment: and can i add an edit functionality to it? for example if i click an item in list view so it should tell me that you want to edit it? if i click yes i should be able to edit it can i do it?

Comment: i study recycler view and implemented it but it's not working please can you help me how to notify it via recycler view that item should be deleted when i close my app and open it again. ThANK YOU

Comment: Is it not possible to notify list view like the method i used? because i am not getting used to recycler view please help me on this

Comment: As far as I understand you can now delete a row from ListView? Next step will be to remove that same record from SQLite database. At the same time you do row removal try calling deleteInformation from UserDbHelper class. I am not sure if the method works, you will need to test that. How to know which data to remove? Well OnItemClickListener provides you position, so you can retrieve the Object to delete with help of this position index and list in your adapter. Similarly as removeRow, you can write a getItem function, which will return you your object based on index provided. Hope this helps

Comment: it gives me an error could you please write me the method which i should write in UserDbhelper class and then call it in dataListAdapter

Comment: please urgas9 help me in writing the method cause it gives me error i am unable to write the correct method.

Comment: Well, I kinda cannot write you delete method. Google for delete SQLite record and write a similar query. It should be simple. You know how to get id of the record (from the existing list).